# Filter Event Calendar by Column

Tags: filter, sharepoint-calendar

I have a SharePoint calendar that I have added a drop down column called `SalesAgent`, which contain Sales Agent names that is selected when event created.  Each agent has numerous events on a calendar.  I need to be able to filter calendar's month view (not list view) with Sales Agent name.  I tried adding different filter web parts, but when I try to connect them the "Send Values To" is grayed out.

I've searched extensively, and I haven't seen a full scale solution for this.  Please help if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot filter the calendar view without using custom code, only the list view of the calendar.